# groovy Map keys with dots - is it possible to use codes rather than strings?

Tags: groovy

i had a case where some yaml read Map structure had a dot in a key and took it literally over into the Map structure inside the Groovy runtime state.

Now i did a little demo on that using Groovy-Console:

```
groovy> Map m = ['a': 'A', 'b': 'B'] 
groovy> m.put('c', 'C') 
groovy> m.put('d', ['z': 'Z']) 
groovy> m.put('d.z', 'DdotZ') 
groovy> println m 
groovy> println m.d.z 
groovy> println m['d.z'] 
groovy> return 0 
 
[a:A, b:B, c:C, d:[z:Z], d.z:DdotZ]
Z
DdotZ
Result: 0
```

With this i can see that d is a key and d.z is as well a key. (plus there is a sub key of z for the key d.)
But for printing key d.z i need a much different coding that for anything else before.

Is there some way of escaping or otherwise (i mean simpler) reference the last item except for the shown method?

Comment: Do you mean `m.'d.z'`?

Comment: `m.get('d').get('z')`, `m.get('d.z')`

Answer (score 0):

by single-quoting the key name the included dot will be part of the key name rather than interpreted as a separator (2nd line is just for demonstration of the vice versa key path - just overly complex as not needing any quotes at all):

```
println m.'d.z'
println m.'d'.'z'
```

these lines will result in:

```
'DdotZ'
'Z'
```

The method might be applicable for other special chars as well, such as spaces.

Comment: based upon original proposal in the question comments from tim_yates